# Is my set theory notation correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

Is my set theory notation  correct?

(1) Every element of $A$ is in $B$

Set theory notation: $\forall x \in A, x \in B$

(2) For every element of set $A$, $P$ is true

Set theory notation: $\forall x \in A$, $P$ is true

Comment: Please carefully explain where to put brackets

Comment: I would not include "is true".  Just: $\forall x \in A,\;P$

Comment: @Joe: I think there are many different bracket conventions.

Comment: (1) can also be written as $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no.

(1) is $\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B)$, (2) is $\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow P(x))$, where $P=P(x)$ is a predicate in the free variable $x$.